# How can make property class create real attribute?

Tags: python-3.x, class, attributes

Use descriptor to manage attribute:

```
class Geeks:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.age = value
    def __getattribute__(self,attr):
        return  object.__getattribute__(self,attr)
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        return  object.__setattr__(self, attr,value)
```

Initialize the `Geeks` class with real attribute `age` 10:

```
boy = Geeks(10)
boy.age
10
boy.__dict__
{'age': 10}
```

The instance `boy` contains a real attribute `age`.
In almost every book,use `property` class to mange the `age` attribute(some in the form of `self.__age` or `self.age_` or `self._age` ,it does not matter):

```
class Geeks:
     def __init__(self,value):
          self._age = value  
     def get_age(self):
         return self._age       
     def set_age(self, value):
         self._age = value 
     age = property(get_age, set_age)
```

Show the property:

```
boy = Geeks(10)
boy.age
10
boy.__dict__
{'_age': 10}
```

The real attribute is `_age` ,not `age`,`_age` is the proxy of `age`,it is a kind of virtual attribute.I have encountered `RecursionError` when to create real `age` attribute with `property(get_age, set_age)`.

```
class Geeks:
     def __init__(self,value):
          self.age = value  
     def get_age(self):
         return self.age       
     def set_age(self, value):
         return self.age = value 
     age = property(get_age, set_age)
```

Same error:

```
class Geeks:
     def __init__(self,value):
          self.age = value  
     def get_age(self):
         return  object.__getattribute__(self,'age')       
     def set_age(self, value):
         object.__setattr__(self, 'age',value)
     age = property(get_age, set_age)
```

How can make `property(get_age, set_age)`  create real attribute `age` ,instead of `_age` or something alike ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Geeks:
     def __init__(self,value):
         self.age = value  
     def get_age(self):
         return self.__dict__['age']       
     def set_age(self, value):
         self.__dict__['age'] = value
     age = property(get_age, set_age)
```

The class `Geeks` can create a real property, the attribute name is same as in `__dict__`.

```
boy = Geeks(10)
in set
boy.age
in get
10
boy.__dict__
{'age': 10}
```